# Can the DataSource of a Kendo UI Diagram sync to a remote API?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, datasource, diagram

I am using a Kendo Diagram to display some data. I do however also want to make and save changes on the diagram.

My diagram is bound to JSON API with a datasource for the diagram nodes and another for the connections [as described here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/diagram#configuration-connectionsDataSource).

However, when I drag a connection from one node to another, the datasource will not send any requests to the API.

Is this supposed to be read-only or am I doing something wrong?

This is my code snippet:

```
var myConnectionsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/my/api",
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json"
        },
        destroy: {
            url: "/my/api",
            type: "delete"
        },
        update: {
            url: "/my/api",
            type: "put",
            dataType: "json"
        },
        create: {
            url: "/my/api",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    change: function(data) {

        // I started hacking in the change event handler to generate API calls myself
        // is this really necessary?

    }
});

var myDiagram = $("#commands-diagram").kendoDiagram({
    dataSource: myNodesDataSource,
    connectionsDataSource: myConnectionsDataSource
}).data('kendoDiagram');
```

Like mentioned in the snippet, I started using the `change` event handler of the connections datasource to find out about changes made and do API calls myself accordingly.

This feels like a weird hack, as the kendo datasources have the transport mechanism that works in other uses (grids and dropdowns).

Comment: Did you look at the [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/diagram/editing)? Try setting `batch: false` on your data source. You do not need the `change` event function.

Comment: wow, I found it. Actually the `batch` parameter had nothing to do with it. I didn't implement all fields for the connections in my API and that caused the datasource to do … nothing :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Brett for making me have another look at the demo.

The datasource required me to implement ALL parameter of a connection (id, from, to, fromX, fromY, toX and toY) no matter whether most of them are always null.

I did only return the `from` and `to` field which displayed correctly but this ways the datasource would never make any calls to the API.